# Not monitor a specific Datasource for Health Check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to know if exist some way to disable the monitoring of a Specific DataSource by SpringBoot Actuator.

**Scenario:**
One Microservice uses 3 Datasources but for some Business Reason, one Datasource of them, it is not necessary to be monitored by Spring Boot Health Indicator.

How to disable the monitoring of one specific DataSource?

Many thanks in advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 31):

I think you'd have to disable the default datasources health indicator, which you can do with this property:

```
management.health.db.enabled=false
```

And then configure your own health indicators which only address the datasources you are interested in, something like this perhaps:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSourceA;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSourceB;

@Bean
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicatorA() {
    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSourceA);
}

@Bean
public DataSourceHealthIndicator dataSourceHealthIndicatorB() {
    return new DataSourceHealthIndicator(dataSourceB);
}
```

Or, alternatively write your own 'multiple datasources health indicator' by extending `AbstractHealthIndicator` and injecting into it only the `Datasources` you are interested in monitoring. Any Spring bean of type `HealthIndicator` will be automatically registered with the `health` actuator so you only have to let Spring create your custom `HealthIndicator` and it will be exposed by the actuator.

For background, you can see how Spring configures the default datasource health check in: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration`.

Comment: Hi @glitch, many thanks for the comment. Do you know what class in Spring Boot add all beans about Datasources?

Comment: @jabrena re this: "what class in Spring Boot add all beans about Datasources" ... I think this class is a good place to start `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration` since it is constructed with a `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration` which must contain all `DataSource` instances discovered in the Spring application context.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring Boot 2, you can filter datasources from the health check by overriding `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbcDataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration`. In the example below datasources without a pool name is filtered.

```
@Configuration
public class YourDataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration extends DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration {

    public NonMigrationDataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources, ObjectProvider<DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider> metadataProviders) {
        // Filter out datasources without a pool name
        super(filterDataSources(dataSources), metadataProviders);
    }

    private static Map<String, DataSource> filterDataSources(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
        return dataSources.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(dataSourceEntry -> {
                    if (dataSourceEntry.getValue() instanceof HikariDataSource) {
                        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = (HikariDataSource) dataSourceEntry.getValue();
                        return hikariDataSource.getPoolName() != null;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize we are a few years later, but I am new to java and cannot locate org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration;   It seems like it might have been consumed within the Contributor but overriding the contributor doesn't exclude the data source.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way will be the following

```
@Configuration
        public class DatasourceHealthCheckConfig  extends DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration {
    
    
        public DatasourceHealthCheckConfig(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources, ObjectProvider<DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider> metadataProviders) {
            super(dataSources, metadataProviders);
        }
    
        @Override
        public HealthContributor dbHealthContributor(Map<String, DataSource> dataSources) {
            // remove the required datasource from the dataSources map by its name
            
            return super.dbHealthContributor(dataSources);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Spring Boot 2.1.2. If you wish to disable healthcheck only for specific datasource. Bit hecky, but worked for me.

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceHealthCheckConfig extends DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration {

  public DatasourceHealthCheckConfig(ObjectProvider<Map<String, DataSource>> dataSources,
                                     ObjectProvider<DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider> metadataProviders) {
    super(filterDataSources(dataSources), metadataProviders);
  }

  private static ObjectProvider<Map<String, DataSource>> filterDataSources(ObjectProvider<Map<String, DataSource>> dataSources) {
    final Map<String, DataSource> map = dataSources.getObject();
    map.remove("specificDataSource"); // name of datasource for removal

    return new ObjectProvider<>() {
      @Override
      public Map<String, DataSource> getObject(Object... args) throws BeansException {
        return map;
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, DataSource> getIfAvailable() throws BeansException {
        return map;
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, DataSource> getIfUnique() throws BeansException {
        return map;
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, DataSource> getObject() throws BeansException {
        return map;
      }
    };
  }
}
```